# Correctly using Scope in rails 4 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope

I'm using scope to fetch a random banner, I'm using the gem Randumb

```
scope :sidebar_top, -> { where(ad_type_id: 2).order_by_rand.first }
```

When no advert is found, all rows are returned. According to the Randumb docs, it should return nil in the instance of nothing being found.

Should I be using scope to return a single instance in the first place? It seems like the best way, but I rarely see scope examples returning less than a small subset.

Any ideas how I can return nil if nothing is found?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? A class method instead of scope.

```
def self.sidebar_top
  where(ad_type_id: 2).blank? ? nil : where(ad_type_id: 2).order_by_rand.first
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much! this also enables me to extend it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use scope to return a single instance. Observe [1]

and as for the answer:

```
def self.sidebar_top
  Array(where(ad_type_id: 2).order_by_rand).first # single query
end
```

[1] scope expects a scope return: If the proc returns nil or false, a scope is returned instead.

```
scope :this_or_all, ->(feeling) { where(state: feeling) if feeling.present? }
```

Hence, you can do this `User.this_or_all(nil).this_or_all(happy)`.